# Cosine and sine Fourier transform of $e^{-\sqrt{x/a}}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to calculate the cosine and sine Fourier transform of $e^{-\sqrt{x/a}}$, i.e.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,e^{-\sqrt{x/a}}\cos(kx)\,dx$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,e^{-\sqrt{x/a}}\sin(kx)\,dx$$

Any suggestion on where to start?

Comment: I would suggest using the [exponential definitions of sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers).

Comment: The $a$-parameter is irrelevant, it can be removed through a suitable substitution. After that,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}} e^{imx}\,dx $$
depends on the (complementary) error function.